# Python 3.x create 3D Volume with 2D slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, slice

**Python 3.x**

I have for loop which is making some calculations and creating one Slice/2D Array lets say (x = 3, y = 3) per iteration and I want at the same time in the same for loop (append?/stack) them in a third dimension.

I have been trying with Numpy stack, vstack, hstack, dstack but I still don't get how to get them together in the 3rd dimension as I want.

So I would like to have at them end something like this:

**(z = 10, x = 3, y = 3)**

```
array([ [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.],
         [1., 1., 1.]], 

        [[2., 2., 2.],
         [2., 2., 2.],
         [2., 2., 2.]],

        .
        .
        .

                     ])
```

Thanks,

Comment: Make a list of the 2D arrays, then pass the list to `np.stack`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I need it. Inside the loop I append them in a list and then outside of the loop I did np.stack(lnew_list, axis = 0). Just to clarify! do you know what is happening under the hood? that np.stack is working with a list

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
arrays = []
for i in range(5):
    arr = np.full((3,3), i)
    arrays.append(arr)

np.asarray(arrays)
```

If you want to you can do np.asarray(arrays) inside loop. But it will be not very efficient. Not that `np.concatenate` will also effectively creates new numpy array so efficiency will be similar. Doing these operation once outside the loop is better